# OWA redirect loop on owa/auth/errorFE.aspx?httpCode=404 with SAML SSO enabled

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server, wif, ws-federation, outlook-web-app

We are trying to set a test environment for Exchange 2013 15.0 ‎(Build 1104.5)‎ with our product. We stumbled upon these links which helped us setting up SSO with Exchange (owa and ecp) :

http://owaauth.com/identity-federation-for-owa-2010-sp1sp2-part-2-of-4/

http://www.theidentityguy.com/articles/2010/10/15/access-owa-with-adfs.html

After some research and dev we made a working PoC with the following user experience :

`GET https://mydomain/owa` -> Redirect to /identityprovider/sso?[authParams]

Here we authenticate the user on our platform and then we POST a request with a SAML1.1 assertion.

`POST https://mydomain/owa` -> Get into OWA or ECP

Everything here works perfectly, the user can send mail, check calendar, etc... OWA is working as expected.

However we go some problems :

There is a strange behaviour with errors. If a user has no mailbox enabled our Exchange server throw a `HTTP 500 Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.UserHasNoMailboxException` error. Then the user is then redirected to `GET /owa/auth/errorfe.aspx?httpError=500` with all the data for printing a nice error. I can find the error on EventViewer.

**BUT**

The server doesn't seems to find **/owa/auth/errorFE.aspx** so it throws a 404 which translate to a 302 redirection to .... `/owa/auth/errorfe.aspx?httpError=404`. And then it loops.

Here is **c:/inetpub/log/LogFiles/W3SCV1** logs which show this scenario :

```
2015-08-18 14:05:32 192.168.122.169 POST /owa/ &CorrelationID=<empty>;&ClientId=RZHCSKVBKKYBNFDWXLYQ&cafeReqId=7a87be7e-8604-4166-9700-2c09f396962d; 443 domain\user 192.168.122.1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Ubuntu;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:38.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/38.0 https://identityprovider/sso?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/&wctx=rm=0&id=passive&ru=/owa/?bO=1&wct=2015-08-18T14:05:11Z&wreply=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/ 302 0 0 265
2015-08-18 14:05:36 192.168.122.169 GET /owa/ bO=1&CorrelationID=<empty>;&ClientId=RZHCSKVBKKYBNFDWXLYQ&cafeReqId=ce366ef2-c53b-4c69-a9d5-a6571898ee0a; 443 domain\user 192.168.122.1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Ubuntu;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:38.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/38.0 https://identityprovider/sso?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/&wctx=rm=0&id=passive&ru=/owa/?bO=1&wct=2015-08-18T14:05:11Z&wreply=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/ 302 0 0 3765
2015-08-18 14:05:36 192.168.122.169 GET /owa/auth/errorfe.aspx httpCode=500&msg=3529056431&msgParam=domain\user&owaError=Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.UserHasNoMailboxException&owaVer=15.0.1104.5&be=EXCHANGE&ts=130843803365507555&CorrelationID=<empty>;&ClientId=RZHCSKVBKKYBNFDWXLYQ&cafeReqId=691c4002-39f0-407b-ad93-5477e8fa49d4; 443 domain\user 192.168.122.1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Ubuntu;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:38.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/38.0 https://identityprovider/sso?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/&wctx=rm=0&id=passive&ru=/owa/?bO=1&wct=2015-08-18T14:05:11Z&wreply=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/ 302 0 0 124
2015-08-18 14:05:36 192.168.122.169 GET /owa/auth/errorFE.aspx httpCode=404&CorrelationID=<empty>;&ClientId=RZHCSKVBKKYBNFDWXLYQ&cafeReqId=51dd01dd-3008-41ac-b07b-a24acf147c3c; 443 domain\user 192.168.122.1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Ubuntu;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:38.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/38.0 https://identityprovider/sso?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/&wctx=rm=0&id=passive&ru=/owa/?bO=1&wct=2015-08-18T14:05:11Z&wreply=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/ 302 0 0 29
2015-08-18 14:05:36 192.168.122.169 GET /owa/auth/errorFE.aspx httpCode=404&CorrelationID=<empty>;&ClientId=RZHCSKVBKKYBNFDWXLYQ&cafeReqId=d9531fd2-2bc9-455c-8d05-5c646c863821; 443 domain\user 192.168.122.1 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Ubuntu;+Linux+x86_64;+rv:38.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/38.0 https://identityprovider/sso?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/&wctx=rm=0&id=passive&ru=/owa/?bO=1&wct=2015-08-18T14:05:11Z&wreply=https://mail.domain.fr/owa/ 302 0 0 31
```

I suspect this behaviour is tied to the SSO configuration which include a passive redirection to our platform for authentication, but I'm not really sure. Here is **Exchange/v15/FrontEnd/HttpProxy/owa/web.config** which define owa federation settings.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </configSections>
  <location inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>

    <!--  Added by Us  -->
    <system.identityModel>
      <identityConfiguration>
        <securityTokenHandlers>
          <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
          <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
          <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <samlSecurityTokenRequirement mapToWindows="true"/>
          </add>
          <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <samlSecurityTokenRequirement mapToWindows="true"/>
          </add>
          <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
          <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        </securityTokenHandlers>
        <applicationService>
          <claimTypeRequired>
            <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" optional="false"/>
          </claimTypeRequired>
        </applicationService>
        <audienceUris>
          <add value="domain.com"/>
        </audienceUris>
        <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <trustedIssuers>
            <add thumbprint="fffffffffff" name="https://idp.com/"/>
          </trustedIssuers>
        </issuerNameRegistry>
      </identityConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel>
    <system.identityModel.services>
      <federationConfiguration>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" path="/"/>
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://idp.com/sso" realm="https://domain.com/owa/" reply="https://domain.com/owa/" requireHttps="true"/>
      </federationConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel.services>
    <!--  /Added by Us  -->

    <system.webServer>
      <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="0"/>

      <!--  Added by Us  -->
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition=""/>
        <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition=""/>
        <!--  /Added by Us  -->

        <remove name="ServiceModel"/>
        <remove name="ServiceModel-4.0"/>
        <remove name="Session"/>
        <remove name="Profile"/>
        <add name="HostHeaderValidationModule" type="Microsoft.Exchange.HttpUtilities.HostHeaderValidationModule, Microsoft.Exchange.HttpUtilities, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="HttpProxy" type="Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.FbaModule,Microsoft.Exchange.FrontEndHttpProxy,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition=""/>
        <add name="cafe_exppw"/>
      </modules>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="35000000"/>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="X-FEServer" value="EXCHANGE"/>
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
      <machineKey decryptionKey="AAAAAA" validationKey="BBBBBBB"/>
      <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false">
        <assemblies>

          <!--  Added by Us  -->
          <add assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
          <!--  Added by Us  -->

          <add assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Strings, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Common, Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Security, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.FrontEndHttpProxy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.Security, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </assemblies>
      </compilation>
      <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="500" maxRequestLength="35000" requestValidationMode="2.0" requestValidationType="Microsoft.Exchange.Security.Authentication.AdfsRequestValidator"/>
      <pages validateRequest="false"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="HttpProxy.ProtocolType" value="Owa"/>
    <add key="OAuthHttpModule.Profiles" value="S2SAppActAs|Callback|V1AppActAs|V1Callback"/>
    <add key="OAuthHttpModule.V1AppScopes" value="user_impersonation"/>
    <add key="OAuthHttpModule.WebAppAuthEnabled" value="15.00.1030.000"/>
<!--
 <add key="LogonSettings.SignOutKind" value="LegacyLogOff" /> 
-->
</appSettings>
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="SecureBinding" maxConnections="100000">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:1009/Microsoft.Exchange.Security.Authentication.FederatedAuthService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding" contract="Microsoft.Exchange.Security.Authentication.FederatedAuthService.IAuthService" name="Microsoft.Exchange.Security.Authentication.FederatedAuthService"/>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <linkedConfiguration href="file://C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\SharedWebConfig.config"/>
</assemblyBinding>
</configuration>
```

Last bit :

When the user has a mailbox not configured (no time zone and language) the user land on **languageselection.aspx**, choose the correct setting and then the server throw a 500 internal error **which is not redirected**. I can't find any error on EventViewer about this error. 
Any ideas why ?

If you have any question, go ahead. Be it configuration files, settings on IIS or Exchange. Anything that seems relevant to you about this problem.